# showing full date & time in datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview, datetime2

I am having an application that shows date and time in `datagridview` after exporting data from database to dataset.

**Details** : I have a column called Date  that contains date and time in datetime2 format and when showing date, seconds don't show up.

```
con = new SqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = my_connection_string;
con.Open();
adap = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Date,Object,ASDU,IOA,Alarm from Alarms_List",my_connection_string);
ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
adap.Fill(ds, "Alarms_List");
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Example : Date table contains  `15/07/2016 10:03:13`
It's shown as : `15/07/2016 10:03`

I have also tried `CAST(Date AS DATETIME2)` in the select statement but none of them works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set the "Format", sample like this :

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss";
```

Answer (score 1):

use :

```
select CONVERT(varchar(19), dateColumnName, 120) from tableName;
```

update:

You may also use the FORMAT function from SQL Server 2012 onwards as below:

```
select FORMAT(dateColumnName, date-format) from tableName;
```

ex

```
select FORMAT(GETDATE(), "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```